Is there a natural interpretation of $e^{-\infty-1}$ in some form of analysis with infinities?
I was considering the parametric function $(x(t), y(t)) = (e^t, e^t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $t \in (-\infty, \infty)$. This draws the ray $y=x$, $x > 0$ when graphed in the $xy$-plane.
It's tempting for one to say "that ray should be extended to a line on the left hand side of the plane" but we have run out of numbers to use since we used all of $t \in (-\infty, \infty)$ to make the ray.
This begs the question is there some extension to the real numbers to include "infinity" so that expressions like $e^{-\infty - 1}$ (or something to that effect) are well defined and do take on negative values?
What I'm concretely looking for is some additional symbols (that I call infinities) and relations to add to $\mathbb{R}$ so that we can evaluate parametric functions of these symbols AND any parametric function which defines a subset of a known algebraic plane-curve, interpolates the ENTIRE curve when considering all of the additional symbols.
In our example we had the algebraic plane curve $x-y=0$ (the line $y=x$), we had the parametric function $(x(t), y(t)) = (e^t, e^t)$ which interpolates just the right half of it, and the goal was to find some symbolic expressions beyond $-\infty$ so that the left half is defined.

I'm too tired to read the post in detail, but this makes me think of the extended real number line: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line

thanks for that link! yes that seems very relevant. In particular some kind of natural "extended extended real number line" is probably the object I am seeking here along with identities like (And these example be wrong by themselves, it just the vague general idea here that important here): $e^{-\infty - 1} = \text{some negative number}, \frac{1}{\infty + 1} = \text{some negative number}$

$\exp(-\infty) = \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{\exp(t)} = 0$. You can flip the $\exp$ by going to complex numbers: $\exp(t+\pi i) = \exp(t)\exp(\pi i) = -\exp(t)$. I don't see why it would be tempting to extend the ray backwards throught the exponential though. Or at least I do not follow the logic of this.

@lightxbulb Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the Riemann Sphere is less than ideal for a few reasons aesthetically. One that the point at infinity is an essential singularity and so $e^{\infty} = e^{-\infty}$ but the limit on the RHS never converges to $0$. Of course for divergent series folks this is nothing unusual but I want to respect continuity here. The second issue is the path you have given is artificial in the sense of “why is $\infty+i*\pi$ the next place to go after visiting $\infty$?”. It’s nicer if $t$ just takes on values on some ordered ring which extends $\mathbb{R}$

Re: “I don’t see why it would be tempting…” that’s a trickier question to answer. A lot of very nice math has been invented by “defining things beyond where it makes sense” whether that’s fractional factorials, fractional dimensions, square roots of $-1$, Etc…. In this case I’m looking for “parametric equations evaluated beyond $-\infty$”. Anyone can just make up some symbols beyond $\infty$ create a well order and call it a day. But requiring them to be algebraically compatible with these parametric equations might force a unique / natural perspective on how to think about this

why i might be wrong there might be some sophisticated reason WHY the next direction to go after $-\infty$ naturally is $-\infty + i\pi$ in almost all cases. I don't even know what such an argument would look like (other than perhaps showing several different parametric curves extend the right way (ideally some not depending on $e^t$ directly)). That would also be a satisfying answer but my gut says that is less likely to be successful than just finding a nice extension of the real line.

"I want to respect continuity here," You can't.

@KurtG. thanks for your comment. After thinking about $S^1$ from your post I think I see the fundamental issue here. If $e^{Q} = -1$ then $e^{\frac{Q}{2}}$ better equal $i$ (or some equivalent symbol in another algebra) and so there will not be a well-order $O$ compatible with the field operations of the real line s.t. the image of $e^x, x \in O$ is both real and can be negative. I think that kills the idea I was hoping for here.

Alternatively, if the law $e^{x+y} = e^{x}e^y$ isn’t true over the well ordered extension then perhaps a negative extension is possible but now we’ve thrown out the baby with the bathwater so that’s not satisfactory either

A tip: if you want to find a value such that the $e$ to the power of that value is some number $a$, you simply should take logarithm of $a$.

"This begs the question is there some extension to the real numbers to include 'infinity' so that expressions like $e^{−∞−1}$ (or something to that effect) are well defined and do take on negative values?"
No, there is no such extension in nonstandard analysis (which is one of your tags).  This is because by the transfer principle, the extension of the exponential function to the hyperreal domain will still be necessarily positive.
You can of course extend to the complex domain and then get negative values.  For example, $e^{\pi i}=-1$.
